# Zip command is killed for very large file by MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line, zip, macos-catalina

I'm trying to zip a large number of very small files using `zip`. The resulting archive is going to be ~80GB. When I execute `zip -r -0 archive.zip dir` the process is killed probably due to resource limits. The console just says `zsh: killed     archive.zip dir` affter a couple of hours. There is a temporary file created with the prefix `zi` that is ~40GB. Is it possible to resume with this temporary file?